# SonarQube ruleset missing

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I want to analyze a .Net project using sonarqube. I am using **sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.3.1.554**
- I have edit the SonarQ.Analysis.xml
- I run the command below

> MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe" begin /key:"AHC" /name:"AHC Project"
>   /version:"1.0" MSBuild.exe" D:\tfs\AHC\MainBranch\TfsCompleteBuild.sln
>   /t:rebuild

and I receive this error

> (Rebuild target) (9) ->   CSC : error CS8035: Error reading ruleset
>   file C:\Windows\system32.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeRoslyn-cs.ruleset -
>   File not found.

Any idea why or how to fix it?

Comment: It is important the current folder to be where the project you are analyzing is, e.g. in your case you should run first `cd D:\tfs\AHC\MainBranch\` and then the commands.

Comment: Each time I try to run it from the sln folder I get this error:
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SonarScanner.Shim.PropertiesWriter.WriteSettingsForProject(ProjectInfo project, IEnumerable`1 files, String fxCopReportFilePath, String codeCoverageFilePath)
   at SonarScanner.Shim.PropertiesFileGenerator.ProcessProjectInfoFiles(IEnumerable`1 projects, PropertiesWriter writer, ILogger logger, String projectBaseDir, String globalSourceEncoding)

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to **sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24** and run the commands from the sln folder as [Valeri - SonarSource Team](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7156760/valeri-sonarsource-team) suggested